# Force install of custom rom on unsupported device (MT6575)

Tags: custom-roms

A friend of mine bought a fake iphone coming from Thailand. It have a fake iOs rom on it which is translated in English but a lot of part aren't... Is there a way to install a CyanogenMod even if the device is not supported ?

Info :

```
BB Chip             : MT6575
MS Board            : mobitek75_ics2
UBoot Ver.          : 2010.06
Kernel Ver          : 3.0.13 (root@zonglibo-desktop) (gcc version 4.4.3 (GCC)
Android Ver.        : 4.2.0
SW Ver.             : ALPS.ICS2.MP.V1.20
Custom Build Verno. : 1371628671
```

Thanks !

Comment: @DanHulme In fact, I know where to find it, the main issue is that none that I found supported my device and I'd like to force the install... That's my question :)

Comment: That won't work and will very likely brick your phone. You need to find a ROM that was built for your exact model of phone.

Comment: I highly doubt if you could flash a custom rom onto this, especially coming from Asia, where those devices are unheard of and more than likely, if not, often, **unsupported**! You may have to dig up chinese forums to find one, not on european/USA sites will have that info...